# How to publish an rpm to an Artifactory-hosted Yum repository using sbt-native-packager?

Tags: scala, sbt, rpm, yum, artifactory

I am trying to publish an rpm built with sbt-native-packager to a yum repository hosted by Artifactory. My project uses the JavaAppPackaging Archetype. I want to publish to the path of my yum repo which is /rhel/linux/7/x86_64. Unfortunately, it is always published to a maven-like path, /artifactId/version/mypackage-version-arch.rpm

Is there some setting I can change to accomplish this?

Comment: I am in a likewise fix, couldn't yet find a solution

Comment: If you won't manage to solve it on the sbt level, you're welcome to use the [Artifactory layout transformation feature](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Layouts) as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Having now set this up, I feel that I can and should publish an answer here.

First, a few assumptions:
 1. We're publishing to Nexus. (Artifactory should be similar but shown here is what worked for Nexus.)
 2. Nexus requires credentials to publish. This complicates issues, hence we override the `publish` task to directly supply credentials.
 3. We're building a server application, hence `JavaServerAppPackaging`. Modify as appropriate.
 4. As part of being a server application, we need a start script. In this case we're using system-v, hence `ServerLoader.SystemV`. Modify as appropriate since most newer Linuxes use Systemd. 
 5. That you'd like to use the `sbt-release` plugin to automate releasing.
 6. Our app is modularized, hence we're using a multi-module sbt build.

`build.sbt` content:

```
import sbtcrossproject.CrossPlugin.autoImport.{CrossType, crossProject}
import NativePackagerHelper._
import ReleaseTransformations._
import scala.sys.process._

// Top-level settings

name := "project-name"
organization in ThisBuild := "com.example"
scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.12.8"


// Integrating with sbt-release plugin   
releasePublishArtifactsAction := {(publish in Rpm).value}

lazy val publishRpmUrl = Def.setting {
  val nexus = "http://nexus.example.com"
  if (version.value.trim.endsWith("SNAPSHOT"))
    ("test-yum-repo", url(nexus + "/repository/test-yum-repo/"))
  else
    ("prod-yum-repo", url(nexus + "/repository/prod-yum-repo/"))
}

// Keep the release plugin happy by having this key set, but disallow remote publishing since
// nothing in this project is sharable.
Global / publishTo := {Option(Resolver.mavenLocal)}

// Settings for root project

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "root",

    // Top-level publishing settings

    publishArtifact in Rpm := true,
    publishLocal in Rpm := {},

    // Standard publish doesn't appear to pass credentials
    publish in Rpm := {
      val creds = Credentials.toDirect(Credentials(Path.userHome / ".sbt" / "nexus.credentials"))
      val (_, destUrl) = publishRpmUrl.value

      Process(
      "curl" :: "-v" ::
        "-u" :: s"${creds.userName}:${creds.passwd}" ::
        "--upload-file" :: (packageBin in Rpm).value.getAbsolutePath ::
        destUrl.toString :: Nil
      ) ! streams.value.log
    },

    // Top-level settings

    mainClass in Compile := Some("com.example.app.Main"),

    // RPM settings

    // package settings
    maintainer := "Acme <info@example.com>",
    packageName in Rpm := "rpm-name",
    packageSummary in Rpm := "Some Summary",
    packageDescription in Rpm := "Some Description",

    // rpm specific
    rpmVendor := "Acme",
    rpmUrl := Some("http://example.com/"),
    rpmLicense := Some("Copyright © 2019 Acme Inc. All Rights Reserved."),
    rpmRequirements ++= Seq("java-1.8.0-openjdk", "bash"),

    linuxPackageMappings in Rpm := configWithNoReplace((linuxPackageMappings in Rpm).value),

    // Java Server Application Archetype
    daemonUser in Rpm := "app-daemon",
    daemonGroup in Rpm := "app-daemon",

    // System loader settings

    // WARN Newer systems will want to use a different loader!
    serverLoading := Some(ServerLoader.SystemV),
    serviceAutostart := true,

    mappings in Universal ++= directory( (sourceDirectory in server).value / "main" / "resources" )
  )
  // Package as normal java server for RedHat RPM running SystemV
  .enablePlugins(RpmPlugin,RpmDeployPlugin)
  .enablePlugins(JavaServerAppPackaging)
  .enablePlugins(SystemloaderPlugin, SystemVPlugin)
  .aggregate(server,client)
  .dependsOn(server,client)

lazy val server = ...
lazy val client = ...
```